# Printing custom objects in C

Tags: c, struct

What is the most common way to print a `struct` in C? For example here is what I'm currently doing to print a `Book`:

```
typedef struct {
    char* title;
    unsigned int year;
} Book;

void print_book(Book book)
{
    printf("{\n\ttitle: \"%s\",\n\tyear: %d\n}\n", book.title, book.year);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    Book hamlet;
    hamlet.title = "The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark";
    hamlet.year = 1603;
    print_book(hamlet);
    return 0;
}
```

```
{
    title: "The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark",
    year: 1603
}
```

Is writing a custom standalone function (such as `print_book`) the most common way to do this? Or is there a way to more tightly bind the 'print' method to the struct/typedef?

Comment: This depends very much on what the output is to be used for. It looks like you're creating some kind of JSON-like object, for which I would rather recommend you use a JSON library to handle all the work.

Comment: Method is an Object-Oriented Programming thing, C does not support OOP. It's common to use such functions. By the way, I think passing a pointer to struct is better as it has less overhead than passing the whole struct.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it doesn't matter to me, I was just formatting it that way for printing -- but it can be formatted any way it's not json

Comment: You can add a pointer to function in the struct, it will allow to create multiple books with different `print` function assigned to them if this is your intent, but it's still not up to the power of OOP

Comment: @XBlueCode could you show an example of what you mean with that?

Comment: Even if you can do OOP in C, the language does not support it really. For example, "to bind a method to a struct (or class)" is an unsupported paradigm. However, if you set the parameter list well, it is kind of bound, because only specific calls are possible.